# I need to find all subgroups of $ G $= {1, -1, i, -i}, with $G \leq$ ($ \mathbb {C}$- {0}, $\cdot$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

If you can guide me with this exercise, to be able to do other similar ones, it would be of great help to me.

Comment: I don't even understand what the group in question is

Comment: $G$ is the group with elements $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$ under usual complex multiplication?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you familiar with cyclic groups?  Your group is a cyclic group of order $4$

Comment: By "$C-0$", do you mean "$\Bbb{C}-\{0\}$"?

Comment: Now yes, I'm new to this, but I edited the question with G well defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to consider the group $G$ as the set $\{\pm 1, \pm i\}$ under regular complex multiplication. Let's see which groups each element generates by self-multiplication:

- $1 \mapsto 1 \implies \{1\}$
- $-1 \mapsto (-1)^2 = 1 \mapsto 1 \implies \{-1,1\}$
- $i \mapsto i^2 = -1 \mapsto -i \mapsto 1 \implies G$
- $-i \mapsto (-i)^2 = -1 \mapsto i \mapsto 1  \implies G$

So you have 2 subgroups: trivial one, full group, and of size 2.

Comment: correction:  $(-i)^2=-1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks, was looking at it and not understand what the problem was :)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand and I can continue doing more exercises